# using Areas in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to achieve the routings as follow:

- http://example.com/Admin/Index
- http://example.com/Application/Index
- http://example.com/Customers/Index

etc...

I like the ideas of using 'Areas' and want to separate all the codes by using Areas.  So, I created my Areas structure like the following screnshot
[image]

and the code in ApplicationAreaRegistration.cs is

```
public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Application";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Application_default",
            "Application/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

However, I cannot achieve the route I want like

http://example.com/Application/Index

In stead of that it becomes, http://example.com/Application/Application/Index

I tried to change the default routing without {controller} in AreaRegistration

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Application_default",
                "Application/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But I got, Controller is required area.

I know I can easily get http://example.com/Application/Index if I put the Controller in root Controllers Folder.  But it means I couldn't group my codes like the Areas anymore and it will be seprated across the MVC Folders.

What I would like to know is, whether I can achieve what I want by using the Areas or am I trying to do which is impossible?

Comment: Do you really need areas to do this? What you are describing is just multiple controllers. You could modify the routing, but it's not necessary in this case.

Comment: For example, what would you like to happen if you add a second controller to an area? What would the URL be then?

Comment: I am not going to add second controller to an area.  If I added it would become 
Application/Application/ActionA
Application/AnotherController/ActionA

Comment: That's why I am confused and posted a question.  I can get what I want if I use multiple controllers.  But I want to group all related codes in the associated Area rather than putting in the Root View/Controllers/Models folders.  
If it is not possible, pls feel free to let me know.

Comment: It's possible as the answer below shows, I'm just confused as to what benefit you think you get from areas instead of controllers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a default controller name to the route so MVC understands what to put in the controller route value when you take it out of the URL.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Application_default",
        "Application/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Application", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: This will break when additional controllers are added to an area.

Comment: Yes. But additional routes could always be added for additional controllers. This does answer the exact question the OP asked.